# how to draw a Horizontal line according to formula calculation result

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

if is it possible to have any small example for what I'm going to ask it's simple but since I'm new to this code language I could not figure it out yet

i have a calculation formula on excel sheet i want to apply it as simple indicator just a Horizontal line to be appeared according to the result of the formula calculation
the formula is " **Close * 0.31 / 10 + Close** " i want to draw line according to the result

i tried to some ways but the line will not be same position as the Formula

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in **hline()** function does not accept series argument, to dynamically plot a horizontal line you should use the **line.new()** function with the equal y1 and y2 argument values, as is shown below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("hline example", overlay = true)
float y = close * 0.31 / 10 + close
if barstate.islast or barstate.isrealtime
    line.new(bar_index, y, bar_index +1, y, extend = extend.both)
```